# How to join 3 tables and get the field with 2 different conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:
Students, Courses (important field Points), StudentCourses (important field Grade).

The exam is passed if Grade is greater than or equal to 70, so student will receive Points.
If Grade is less than 70, student will not receive Points.
Student is graduated if sum of his credits is greater than 10.

I need to select StudentName, sum of his PASSED Points, average of his ALL grades. 
I could select StudentName, sum of his PASSED Points and average of his PASSED grades. But I need average of ALL grades.

I wrote the following query.

```
SELECT s.Name, SUM(c.CreditPoints) AS CreditPoints, AVG(sc.Grade) AS 
AverageGrade FROM Students s JOIN StudentCourse sc
ON s.Id = sc.StudentId
JOIN Courses c ON c.Id = sc.CourseIdenter code here
WHERE sc.Grade >= 70
GROUP BY s.Name
HAVING SUM(CreditPoints) > 10
ORDER BY CreditPoints
```

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Can you show us what is exactly what doesn't work well with the query you just wrote? What are your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you want to select only the student's name make sure that you `group by` student's id also (I believe there is a column in the `Students` table) becaus ethere would be 2 students with the same name.
You must not use this condition:

```
WHERE sc.Grade >= 70
```

because this will remove the rows with Grade < 70 which you need to calculate the average.
So the sum of creditpoints will be calculated with a CASE statement:

```
select 
  s.Id, s.Name,
  sum(case when sc.grade >= 70 then c.creditpoints else 0 end) CreditPoints,
  avg(sc.grade) AverageGrade 
from students s 
inner join studentcourse sc on s.id = sc.studentid 
inner join courses c on c.id = sc.courseid
group by s.id, s.Name
having sum(case when sc.grade >= 70 then c.creditpoints else 0 end) > 10
order by CreditPoints desc;
```

Since you are using SQL Server you can't use the alias `CreditPoints` in the `HAVING` clause so you have to repeat the `CASE` statement.

Comment: See my edited answer for the having clause. You tagged sql server a few mins ago and I edited.

Comment: Thank you! I received the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sc.Grade >= 70 THEN c.CreditPoints ELSE 0 END) AS CreditPoints_passing,
       AVG(CASE sc.Grade >= 70 THEN sc.Grade END) AS AverageGrade_passing
       AVG(sc.Grade) AS AverageGrade
FROM Students s JOIN
     StudentCourse sc
     ON s.Id = sc.StudentId JOIN
     Courses c ON c.Id = sc.CourseIdenter code here
GROUP BY s.Name
HAVING CreditPoints_passing > 10  -- I think you want only 10 passing credits here
ORDER BY CreditPoints;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what issue you are facing. To me only issue I can see is GROUP BY  s.Name as multiple student may have the same name and probability there to have unexpected results from the input set. You should better use s.ID for GROUP by as below-

```
SELECT 
....
GROUP BY s.Id  -- Change the grouping Key
HAVING SUM(CreditPoints) > 10
ORDER BY CreditPoints
```